# What to Use for mobile development

Tags: .net, mobile

I have to design a mobile portal that has support for support Android,BlackBerry and IPhone. Shall I use eclipse, .Net framework or something else.

I have written a test application using .net 3.5 and it renders and works well for all the required platforms (Android,BlackBerry and IPhone), so not sure what I am going to miss if I use .net.

Comment: this is a server-side toolset and the phones view the pages with a browser?

Comment: I'm not sure if the OP geninely doesn't know what he's talking about, or may be what he meant was "which server side framework has good tools/libraries for producing mobile-specific content". Because there's a difference between a web page that is mobile-centric and desktop-bound. I personally would LOVE to know the answer to the latter.

Comment: @Will, correct all I want to know is that if I use ASP and C# what is its advantage and disadvantage. After the app is under development I don't want to curse the decision, so want to be clear what I am going to miss if I follow  ASP and C# .

Answer (score 1):

Server-side language has nothing to do with how well it can serve up mobile pages. What's more important is what you're comfortable with.

Comment: Dan - see my comment to the question. The HTML/JS generated for mobile platforms is different than one for desktops, and as such there may be assorted back-end libraries/toolsets making generating this content easier.

Comment: @DVK HTML doesn't change from desktop to mobile, especially if you're only targeting smart phones. Android/iPhones have great JS support, and BlackBerry doesn't do too bad. .NET won't generate output that can't be rendered in all mobile platforms, however it is possible for a programmer to generate content that a mobile device can't handle. This has more to do with the programmer than the framework, however. Choose what your developers are most comfortable with. You'll be able to develop faster and with more ease and less headaches.

Comment: having perused web pages from the same web sites which were mobile optimized and not on my BBerry, I can authoritatively state that there's a MAJOR difference in experience. There's a difference between "can be rendered" and "is useful and usable considering device limitations" as far as user experience. Think both screen size, bandwidth and controls.

Comment: @DVK I don't mean to say that you can use desktop pages on mobile devices. What I mean is that the tags & standards allowed are the same. The strategy used for targeting mobile devices needs to be different, but this is separate from the server-side implementation details and is not going to be impeded by using .NET

Answer (score 0):

I have written the same in .NET with no issues.  The master page model seems to fit very well with mobile rendering.